# Subquery com left join

Tags: sql, query, oracle, join, pl-sql

estou tentando fazer uma busca de registros em uma tabela onde o produto não possui determinadas características. Gostaria de exibir somente os registros que não possuem estas características, mesmo que exista várias outras, tentei com o a query abaixo, quase deu certo, rs. Agradeço pela atenção e colaboração.

```sql
select CODPROD
    from PRODUTOS
    left join (select CODPROD as CODPROD1, CARACT
                from PRODUTOS
                where DTFIM = '99991231'
                    and CARACT in ('X001','X002','X003')
                    and CODPROD <> ' '
                group by (CODPROD,CARACT))
     on CODPROD = CODPROD1
     group by CODPROD
```

Comment: Não entendi a necessidade de uma subquery, o que exatamente você quer trazer? Seria o CARACT in ('X001','X002','X003') ou a negação disso?

Answer (score 0):

Analisando seu caso acredito que não é necessário utilizar o **Subquery**, mas eu recomendaria criar o código da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CODPROD, CARACT 
FROM PRODUTOS
WHERE CODPROD NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CODPROD
                  FROM PRODUTOS 
                  WHERE DTFIM = '99991231' 
                  AND CARACT IN ('X001','X002','X003')
                  AND CODPROD <> ' ')
GROYP BY CODPROD, CARACT
```

Utilizei a **Subquery** em um **Where** apenas buscando as informações necessários pelo **CODPROD**.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda não deu certo, desta forma agrupado por (CODPROD, CARACT) retorna muitos registros para o mesmo produto, preciso que retorne apenas 1, ou seja o produto que não tem as características x001,x002 e x003.

Comment: E se você fizesse AND CARACT NOT IN ('X001','X002','X003') já que não quer exibir essas características?

Comment: Eu alterei para NOT IN, faz um teste.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo com a seguinte query:

SELECT CODPROD
FROM PRODUTOS
WHERE CODPROD NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CODPROD
      FROM PRODUTOS 
      WHERE DTFIM = '99991231' 
       AND CARACT IN ('X001','X002','X003')
       AND CODPROD <> ' ')
    and CODPROD <> ' '
GROUP BY CODPROD